# emacs keybinding to compile C file

Tags: c, emacs

Here's what I would like to do: When C-c C-l is pressed, a new terminal window is launched if there is no terminal window already, then, in that terminal, gcc is invoked with some flags and the current buffer's file. How would I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the built in:

```
M-x compile gcc ...
```

`compile` isn't bound to any keys by default, but you could do something like:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 
          (lambda () (define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'compile))))
```

There are a bunch of packages people have written around compiling on the Emacs Wiki.  Check out [SmartCompile](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartCompile), [CompileCommand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand), and the category [Programmer Utils](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryProgrammerUtils).

The benefit of using `M-x compile ...` over just running it in a "terminal" is that you get <kbd>C-x `</kbd> (aka `next-error`) which will jump you to the file and line that caused the error command.  And there's the command <kbd>M-x recompile</kbd> which does what you'd expect.  And, of course, like all Emacs commands, the `compile` command keeps a history of the compile calls and you can go through the history with <kbd>M-p</kbd> and <kbd>M-n</kbd>.

Comment: You should note that after running `M-x compile` once you can use `M-x recompile` to run the same command as last time.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly this to run my perl unit tests in a nearby `eshell`: http://github.com/jrockway/elisp/blob/master/_local/cperl-extras.el#L15

The general shape of the code is:

```
(defun run-in-eshell (cmd use-hidden-eshell-p)
  (with-current-buffer (eproject-eshell-cd-here use-hidden-eshell-p)
    (eshell-preinput-scroll-to-bottom)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert cmd)
    (eshell-send-input nil t)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (ignore-errors
      (set-window-point (get-buffer-window) (point-max)))))
```

`eproject-eshell-cd-here` is what actually finds the eshell buffer.
If you don't want to install
[eproject](http://github.com/jrockway/eproject), then you can just
loop through the buffers and find it yourself.